# When using \multicols and inserting a wrapped table, how do I prevent text from being pushed to the margin (see pic)?

Tags: margins, multicol, wrapfig

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Standard packages for figures, citations, math, tables, etc.
% Feel free to add more as needed!
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\taninv}{arctan}

\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500 
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

  
% Packages for formatting with 1 in margins and doublespacing
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{0cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
}

\usepackage{sectsty}% http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty
\usepackage{titlecaps}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlecaps

% titles are medium weight and centered
\sectionfont{\normalfont\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE {Lab Report 0 - Introduction to the Laboratory} \\ \vspace{8pt}}
{\large Names  \\ \vspace{0pt}}
{\large Laboratory Section AB4, TAs: Names\\ \vspace{0pt}}
{\large August 26, 2021} \\
{\large email}\\
{\large email} \vspace{40pt}
\end{center}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\textbf{\emph{Abstract} -- In Part 1, the voltage and current behavior of a rectifier circuit constructed using both diodes and an SCR box across a resistive load was examined. In Part 2, the output voltage signal of an FET box over a resistive load was examined with respect to varying duty cycle and frequency.}


\section{Introduction}


\section{Theory}


\section{Results}
In Part 1 of the lab, a two-phase AC supply was fed into two types of rectifier circuits. The first rectifier circuit was constructed out of two diodes connected in series with each phase of the voltage source, both leading to a common output resistor. The current through a single diode, as well as the voltage and current across the common resistor, are displayed in Figure 1. The current through the diode exhibits the positive half of a sine wave for half of its shape, and maintains a value of 0 for the other half. This shape reflects the fact that the diode can only be activated by positive voltage, hence the positive sine wave portion of the waveform, and will not produce any current if exposed to a negative voltage, hence the 0-value half of the waveform. The voltage and current across the common resistor, which are in phase with one another, as expected for a purely resistive element, are constantly exhibiting the positive half of a sine wave. This is due to the two-phase nature of the voltage source, because when one phase voltage is negative (hence not producing any diode current), the other will be positive. The measured values of resistor voltage, current, and power are displayed in Table 1. 

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Pt1Diodes.png}
\caption{Oscilloscope output of diode current (Ch.1), voltage across the resistor (Ch.2), and current across the resistor (Ch.3) of a diode rectifier.}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{wraptable}{l}{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Resistor Parameter  & Value  \\
\hline
$V_{RMS}$   & 26.7 V    \\
$V_{avg}$   & 23.7 V    \\
$I_{RMS}$   & 0.536 A   \\
$P$     & 14.95 W   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Diode-based rectifier measured values.}
\label{table:ta}
\end{wraptable} 


The second rectifier circuit was constructed from a silicon-controlled rectifier (SCR) unit, again connected to a two-phase AC source on one end and a common resistor on the other. The measured current and voltage waveforms from this circuit are shown in Figure 2, and follow a similar pattern to that of Figure 1. However, instead of current being activated as soon as the voltage source produces positive voltage, as it was with the diode-based rectifier circuit, the SCR box exhibits a delay, leading to flat 0-value sections of the resistor voltage/current. This delay is controllable due to the fact that the SCR box is made up of thyristors, which are more controllable than simple diodes because a third terminal (the gate) must receive a signal pulse in order to allow current through. The measured values of resistor voltage, current, and power are displayed in Table 2.   


\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

I'm using \multicols for a two-column document and trying to insert tables and figures within each column using wrapfig and wraptable. However, on wraptable LaTeX decided to push the text that was supposed to come after the table all the way to the right margin (outside of the second column - see pic). I'm having a lot of trouble doing anything to fix this, any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Can you please edit your question, AND insert all necessary code, which contains your problem (so we can copy, compile and work with it), AND enclose it within the {} from the editor icon? I.e. unless I'm blind I don't see, how you use multicols here. // Keeping the screenshot is fine. // May be it's a good idea to post the image or link to the .png file. // Thanks

Comment: Added the code above^

Comment: it is very strange to use wrapfigure with a width of \linewidth, the whole point of the package is to make a cutin so text wraps around the figure, but with `\linewidth` it is full width so will simply appear before the paragaph (which could be done trivially without the complicated code of that package) you are specifying that tex tries to fit the first few lines into the remaining 0pt to the right of the image so it's not that surprising it fails.

Comment: I can't just use normal figure b/c I need the figures/tables to be inserted within the bounds of one of the two columns since the doc is divided into 2 columns

Comment: @Jack, just wondering about the way you use multicols. The documentclass article is designed to yield a two column layout. See e.g. here for a print https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FlLdii.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Ftex.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F782%2Fwhat-are-the-available-documentclass-types-and-their-uses&tbnid=mfCy9P0iKrD9lM&vet=12ahUKEwjP9eWpgdLyAhWF6qQKHeHwDUUQMygCegUIARCmAQ..i&docid=PFk4-m3XqcrBvM&w=586&h=833&q=latex%20documentclass%20article&client=firefox-b-d&ved=2ahUKEwjP9eWpgdLyAhWF6qQKHeHwDUUQMygCegUIARCmAQ  or tag [article] here.

Comment: In other words: you try to repeat what is already provided. // Suggestion: 1) Save a copy of your file. 2) Rebuild it with documentclass{article}, WHILE leaving out all fancy stuff. Just use regular \section{} and what have you as in any other document. 3) Start with text only, compile and check. Add Image, later table. // It will turn out to be easier and cleaner code. With {article}, as a kind of indicator, whenever you feel you have to fiddle with formatting ... it's most likely not needed.

Comment: In this situation, you don't have to use `wrapfigure` at all.  Just use a `minipage` at the desired location and add the caption using the facilities of `captionof`.

Answer (score 1):

For your reference, this is how the rebuilding-process could look like:

```
% check out manual at https://ctan.org/pkg/article?lang=en
% say, that you want two columns
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}
    % specify title, author etc.
    \title{Lab Report 0 - Introduction to the Laboratory}
    \author{Laboratory Section AB4}
    % show it
    \maketitle

    % here's the abstract
    \begin{abstract}
    In Part 1, the voltage and current behavior of a rectifier circuit constructed using both diodes and an SCR box across a resistive load was examined. In Part 2, the output voltage signal of an FET box over a resistive load was examined with respect to varying duty cycle and frequency.
    \end{abstract}

    \section{Introduction}


    \section{Theory}


    \section{Results}
    In Part 1 of the lab, a two-phase AC supply was fed into two types of rectifier circuits. The first rectifier circuit was constructed out of two diodes connected in series with each phase of the voltage source, both leading to a common output resistor. The current through a single diode, as well as the voltage and current across the common resistor, are displayed in Figure 1. The current through the diode exhibits the positive half of a sine wave for half of its shape, and maintains a value of 0 for the other half. This shape reflects the fact that the diode can only be activated by positive voltage, hence the positive sine wave portion of the waveform, and will not produce any current if exposed to a negative voltage, hence the 0-value half of the waveform. The voltage and current across the common resistor, which are in phase with one another, as expected for a purely resistive element, are constantly exhibiting the positive half of a sine wave. This is due to the two-phase nature of the voltage source, because when one phase voltage is negative (hence not producing any diode current), the other will be positive. The measured values of resistor voltage, current, and power are displayed in Table (use a ref here)


\end{document}
```

**Result**:

[image: Result]

**Hint**: The User Manual for article is a bit peculiar, as it mixes both user syntax and implementation. As a rule of thumb:

- the margins will tell you the commands to use in regular Latex-code
- if in doubt, search either the index or the whole User Manual
- most frequently you'll probably only need `Ch. 7 Document Markup`